# How can I retrieve AWS Account Name from within a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template in which I would like to output a variable that contains the name of the account that the template was deployed to.

I've found a way to retrieve the Account Id via this Psuedo Parameter:

```
AWS::AccountId
```

This is described on the Pseudo Parameters Reference page here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

I'd like to know if there's any way to do the same for the Account Name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by "account name". In AWS you only have the following **two** [AWS account identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html):

- AWS account ID
- Canonical user ID

My guess is that you are referring to [account alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html#AboutAccountAlias). If so, there is no direct way of getting it from CFN. But you can design your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CFN. The resource would be in the form of a **lambda function** which would use AWS API [ListAccountAliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccountAliases.html) to list the account aliases and return them to your template for further use.

Comment: From the AWS console, if I click on my username at the top, then select "My Account", I see an "Account Name" value listed in the "Account Settings" section.  Is this the same as an "account alias"?

Comment: @Avalanchis No. This is your IAM user name.

Comment: Actually it was the Account Alias I was wanting to retrieve.  I found it on the IAM dashboard.  Thanks!